# Getting ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms while executing simple query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following schema defined as mentioned [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca14b/1)
While executing the query

`SELECT stn.id 
    FROM station stn 
    JOIN station_location_mpng stnloc 
    ON stn.oid = stnloc.station_oid 
    WHERE stnloc.location_oid = ?;`

Am getting the following exception

```
ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
01775. 00000 -  "looping chain of synonyms"
```

This is occurring in one of my DB instance. Am a java developer not DBA could anyone point out why am getting exception as above.

Comment: How the above will related to my question?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's called from Java or not. It is a general Oracle error and something is wrong one the DB side. As the message suggests, the problem is most likely with looping synonyms for the tables on your DB. In that question I've linked people tell how to find out what is wrong. I'd problably start with the answer of Justin Cave (3rd one).

Comment: @Amongalen I found the problem. My DB instance has N schema so I just need to mention the SCHEMA name in front of table, to work properly.

Comment: You probably should post your solution as an answer to this question and accept it just so it is more visible.

Comment: "How the above [duplicate] will relate to my question?" As stated in the top answer of the duplicate, this is commonly caused by a synonym pointing to an object that does not exist (or your current user does not have permissions to access). In your case you found a solution by adding a schema to the object identifier so that it could be correctly referenced.